# How to find the difference between campaign dates and filter date

Tags: php, date

I have 4 dates with me, 2 for campaign one of them is campaign start date and the other one is for campaign end date and the same thing goes for filter dates. Now I want to check how many days my campaign runs in between a given filter start date and filter end date . I am using these conditions but

```
if ($datecs != FALSE && $datece != FALSE && $datefs != FALSE && $datefe != FALSE) {
    if( ($datecs >= $datefs) && ($datece <= $datefe)) {
        // campaign start and end date between filterdates
        $tot_days = $this->get_days($datecs,$datece);
        if($tot_days != 'ok'){
                return $tot_days;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
    } elseif (($datecs <= $datefs) && ($datece >= $datefe)) {
        //filterdates between campiagn start and end
        $tot_days = $this->get_days($datefs,$datefe);
        if($tot_days != 'ok'){
            return $tot_days;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } elseif(($datecs <= $datefs ) && ( $datece <= $datefe ) && ($datece >= $datefs)) {
        // campaign end date between filterdates
        $tot_days = $this->get_days($datefs,$datece);
        if ($tot_days != 'ok'){
            return $tot_days;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } elseif(( $datecs>= $datefs) && ($datece >= $datefe) && ($datecs <= $datefe )) {
        // campaign start date between filterdates
        $tot_days = $this->get_days($datecs,$datefe);
        if (($tot_days != 'ok')) {
            return $tot_days;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

datecs is the campaign start date and datece is campaign end date .datefs is the filter start date and datefe is filter end date. And get_days function gets me the number of days this get_days function I am using

```
function get_days($date1,$date2)
    {
        if($date2 > $date1)
        {
            $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
            return $interval->days+1;
            //we add one because it will not calculate the starting date if we substract. 
            //It will give the number of days to reach last date.
        } else if($date2 = $date1) {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return "ok";
        }
    }
```

Please Let me know if I am going wrong some where.

Comment: What is the type of $date1 and $date2 in the function ger_days ? I mean you are passing string or date ?

Comment: I am passing datecs/datefs/datece/datefe in get_days function it is string at first but I am converting them to date using DateTime function for example :   $datecs = new DateTime($startdate);

Comment: I agree with you on == . but i don't agree on the second condition $date2 < $date1. It should $date2 > $date1.

Comment: Then the problem is in the first function, look my **EDIT**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrite your get_days function :

```
function get_days($date1,$date2)
{
  if($date2 < $date1)
  {
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    return $interval->days;
  } else if($date2 == $date1) {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

I don't know if that what you want but i found 2 mistakes :

1) you are using `=` and not `==` to compare

2) you swapped in the comparaison : it's `$date2 < $date1`

Also it's better to return 0 is it failed> Try to not mix return type in a same function, it will make your code easier to understand.

This worked for me.

**EDIT**

In your second condition (second line) You are doing :

`if ($datecs >= $datefs) { 
get_days($datecs,$datece); }`

And then if the function get_days : `if ($date2 > $date1)`

That means you are doing

```
if ($datecs >= $datefs) 
  then if ($datecs < $datefs)
    //do some stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using php carbon. It's a great library that has a lot of functionality that could make this simpler and easier to read and understand.

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/